# performance issue on treeset#add

Tags: java, treeset

In my application I use a `TreeSet` like an ordered queue. I have profiled my application and I spend 25% of my cpu time on adding elements to the `TreeSet` but only 2% on popping the last element. Is there a better collection for an ordered queue? Could it be more performant to add to a `LinkedList` and sort it everytime I need to consume the queue?

Comment: What about https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html and the various implementations?

Comment: Or even a [PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

Comment: If you use a `TreeSet` it means your elements implement `Comparable`; is that what you want?

Comment: Yes all elements are implementin comparable, the PriorityQueue is indeed slightly faster, even I have to use the reverse comperator

Comment: @Ferrybig until there is no faster solution, I would accept the priority queue as an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use a [`PriorityQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) in stead of a `TreeSet` because that is make for queue's.

`TreeSet` has performance problems when using it as a Queue because its internal tree structure isn't suited for usage as queues. This is because its internal structure is based on a `TreeMap`, withs uses a [red black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree), and this tree needs to move many elements around to accommodate for insertions that replace the top elements. In some conditions, this requires a full rebuild of the tree.

Using a `PriorityQueue` is simple:

```
PriorityQueue<YourObject> queue = new PriorityQueue<>();
```

Unlike a `TreeSet`, a `PriorityQueue` does allow duplicate elements, and gives them back in a FIFO order.

If you need a treadsafe solution, you should use a [`PriorityBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) instead.

Comment: thanks for the hint "allow duplicate element", because it is crucial to use a proper initial size to gain best performance

Comment: TreeSet uses TreeMap, which uses a red-black tree, which by definition can never become unbalanced. However it is certainly preferable to use a PriorityQueue for this task.